# Building HTTP headers in Rocket 0.5-rc (migrating from 0.4)

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am working on a project which was build using rust-nightly a year ago and try to migrate it to a recent rustc-stable.

It used rocket 0.4 and I am [migrating this to 0.5-rc.2](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/upgrading/).

There are those imports:

```
use rocket::http::hyper::header::{ContentDisposition, DispositionType, DispositionParam, Charset};
```

I replaced that with

```
use rocket::http::hyper::header;
```

Now before it was possible to build the filename header by a struct:

```
            .header(ContentDisposition {
                disposition: DispositionType::Attachment,
                parameters: vec![DispositionParam::Filename(
                Charset::Iso_8859_1, // The character set for the bytes of the filename
                None, // The optional language tag
                format!("reviews_{}.csv", unix_time)
                    .into_bytes() // the actual bytes of the filename
                )]
```

Is there way to do this in 0.5 as well, or do I have to format / create the header manually, like this:

```
            .header(header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION {
                disposition: "attachment",
                parameters: .... // create filename header manually
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to work - I am still wondering if that is the intended and optional solution:

```
.header(Header::new(header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION, format!("attachment; reviews_{}.csv", unix_time).into_bytes()))
```

As I only have ASCII characters I left out the charset code.